# Quick to develop web app in Java

Tags: java, web-applications

I need to develop a basic web app very quickly (1 week) for a demo.

My requirements are

- Java (I need to make use of existing Java libraries to access the relevant data)
- 2 screens
- One for static data view, maybe some search parameters
- Other for basic form entry
- No fancy AJAX required
- Ideally easy for a web designer to come in and tart it up as necessary, without having to rewrite everything

My first stop was going to be to checkout Wicket as I've heard good things about it.  I don't have the time right now to dive into anything heavy, which probably writes off JSF in my mind (I played with JSF1, steep learning curve which I've now slid back down).

I'm happy to treat the result as throwaway so if there's a framework which starts of well but then doesn't scale up to bigger projects, that would be ok.

Any suggestions appreciated on frameworks/approach.

Comment: What is your knowledge of core Java?  What is your knowledge of other languages running on the JVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest the [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) which has the huge advantage to be full Java (so less learning curve if you don't know Groovy). Check out the demo!

Answer (score 9):

[Spring roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) can very quickly create web applications using [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) for CRUD, and tarting it up later. Check out the [Keynote from Google I/O 2010](http://www.youtube.com/googledevelopers) (Especially [Day 1, Part 9](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQHlhIIxCIc)) where the skeleton of a basic expense tracking application is developed from scratch in about 2 minutes.

GWT support is in [Roo 1.1.0.M1](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/05/19/spring-roo-1-1-0-m1-released/)

> As a milestone release, Roo 1.1.0.M1 isn't intended for mission-critical use.

It is probably easiest to get in the form already integrated with the eclipse based [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/springsource-google-download)

Comment: +1 For Roo sounds just like the OP needs

Answer (score 5):

Use Groovy/Grails.  Full access to all Java libraries and you will be done so much faster it will make your head spin.

This is from a hardcore java user, by the way.  It's just not the appropriate language for most web apps.

Oh, you could probably also use JRuby on rails.

Comment: +1 for Grails.  This will be alive and kicking in short order, and you'll be able to add in some nice stuff like security without much effort.  AJAX isn't hard, either.

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine. There are some good video tutorials from Google that get you up and running in no-time.

http://code.google.com/appengine/

Intro (< 10 min): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfgO-LXGpTM

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CUBA platfrom](https://www.cuba-platform.com/), it matches your requitements.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). It works on Google App Engine too if this is an internet app.